# Android 12 or newer - Crash when changing device connection type to bluetooth

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, bluetooth, android-12

I'm new to kotlin/android programming.
I am trying to fix program crashing when selecting a device connection type to bluetooth. This only happens in android 12 or newer.

This is a code fragment in kotlin related to bluetooth device connection:

```
private fun onItemSelected(view: View, printer: PosPrinter) {
        var connectionType = printer.connectionType
        when (view.id) {
            R.id.connectionLayout -> {
                val selectedConnection = connectionAdapter.selected?.first ?: ConnectionType.IP
                if (selectedConnection != connectionType) {
                    connectionType = selectedConnection
                    if (model.triggerConnectivityChange(connectionType))
                        if (connectionType == ConnectionType.BT) showBtSelectDialog()
                        else if (connectionType == ConnectionType.USB) showUSBSelectDialog()
                }
            }
            R.id.protocolLayout -> {
                val protocol = protocolAdapter.selected?.first ?: PrintProtocol.ELZAB_STX
                model.selectedProtocolChange(protocol)
            }
        }
        handleVisibilityElements(connectionType)
    }

    private fun showBtSelectDialogInternal() {
        ListSelectDialog.Builder<IODevice, LayoutSelectItemListBinding>(appActivity)
            .apply {
                title(R.string.select_bt_device)
                applyItemLayout(R.layout.layout_select_item_list)
                applyFunction { binding, dialog ->
                    IODeviceHolder(dialog, binding) {
                        model.selectedConnectionChange(ConnectionType.BT, it)
                        handleVisibilityElements(ConnectionType.BT)
                    }
                }
                applyList(appActivity.resolveBTDevices().map { IODevice.parse(it) })
                headerIcon(R.drawable.ic_bluetooth)
                titleColor(Helper.uiModeDialogColors(isDarkMode))
                headerIconColor(Helper.uiModeDialogColors(isDarkMode))
                dialogBackgroundColor(Helper.uiModeDialogColors(isDarkMode))
                tintAll(R.color.iconBlue)
            }.create().show(childFragmentManager, null)
    }

    private fun showBtSelectDialog() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED){
                showProgress()
                bluetoothEnabler.launch(BluetoothUtils.turnBluetoothOn())
            }
        }
    }

    private val bluetoothEnabler: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = forResult {
        hideProgress()
        if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) showBtSelectDialogInternal()
    }
```

And this is a permission related code in my android manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"
        android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
        android:minSdkVersion="31"
        tools:targetApi="s" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"
        android:minSdkVersion="31"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="32"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

I've tried some other solutions I found on the internet but they didn't worked or I didn't know how to adjust them into this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not enough to declare Bluetooth permissions in the manifest file. Bluetooth permissions are [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/bt-permissions#declare-android12-or-higher) and the application must obtain user consent to use the corresponding Bluetooth feature.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67722950/android-12-new-bluetooth-permissions/69972855#69972855) is a Stack Overflow answer on how to get these runtime permissions.

And here is the corresponding source code example from the link:

```kotlin
//check android12+
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                            requestMultiplePermissions.launch(arrayOf(
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT))
                        }
                        else{
                            val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
                            requestBluetooth.launch(enableBtIntent)
                        }
....................................................

private var requestBluetooth = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    //granted
                }else{
                    //deny
                }
 }

private val requestMultiplePermissions =
                registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
                    permissions.entries.forEach {
                        Log.d("test006", "${it.key} = ${it.value}")
                    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
It says that BLUETOOTH_SCAN, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT and RESULT_OK are unresolved references

Comment: @Fishu85 I like to answer with a quote from Randy Pausch: _“The brick walls are there for a reason. The brick walls are not there to keep us out. The brick walls are there to give us a chance to show how badly we want something. Because the brick walls are there to stop the people who don’t want it badly enough. They’re there to stop the other people.”_

Comment: @Fishu85 remember the question you asked a month ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77203431/unresolved-reference-viewmodels

Comment: of course I remember the question but this time invalidating caches didn't worked

Comment: I've changed Manifest.permission to android.Manifest.permission and changed RESULT_OK to Activity.RESULT_OK and it worked out but I don't really understand why